# Firefox freezes when downloading file

Tags: firefox, freeze, download

I found today very interesting and annoying problem with Firefox. I tried to download Android Studio (1.1Gb) and after ~70Mb my browser just freezes and CPU usage raises. I force closed Firefox and restarted it, same thing. Did this more than ten times, no difference. I'm able to use my browser with no problems after I cancelled the download. I use the default download location and SSD. My Firefox version is 43.0a2 (Developer Edition).

What I tried so far:

1. Googleing
2. Safe Mode

Comment: Does it do this with all downloads?

Comment: Have you tried with the release edition?

Comment: @Moab No, only when downloading something BIG.

Comment: @DavidPostill Not yet, need to download it first =D

Answer (score 0):

Try an external download manager with Firefox to allow multiple connections, greatly speeding downloads. [Free Download Manager](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) and [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) are well integrated into Firefox (although they can also run inside IE or other browser and independently). They free up the browser to perform it main function: browsing the web.

One caution: be careful to check the reputation of any download manager, or any add-on, for that matter, as some are malware.

Comment: Tried with DownThemAll! and now Firefox freezes after 1Mb..

Comment: Have you tried Free Download Manager? Run that from its own interface, without Firefox, and that would prove if there's an issue with the web site cutting off the DL, or perhaps your ISP.

Comment: I writed my own little download tool and that works fine.